# SQL Server aggregate functions - how to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

Input table contains 2 columns i.e. name and dept

```
+------+------+
| name | dept |
+------+------+
| A    |  123 |
| B    |  456 |
| A    |  789 |
| C    |  123 |
| A    |  456 |
| B    |  789 |
+------+------+
```

Output is

```
name
-----
A
```

so here A is working in 3 depts (123, 456, 789). How to retrieve the name who is working in all the 3 depts?

Comment: What defines `all`?  Is there another table for `departments`?  Or do you just want the `name` associated with the highest count?

Comment: no only single table is there and just i want to retrieve the name who are working in all the departments

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DEPT) = 
                             (
                              SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DEPT)
                              FROM TABLE1
                             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using a `window function`:

```
select name
from (
    select name, count(distinct dept) cnt, 
           count(distinct dept) over () overallcnt
    from yourtable
    group by name
) t
where cnt = overallcnt
```

Comment: it is showing an error i.e. Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.

Comment: @AjitKumar -- I thought this was supported in oracle 11, but I could be mistaken...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DEPT)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DEPT) FROM TABLE1 )
```

Comment: thanks sagar but if we dont know how many depts are there and we want to retrieve the names who are working in all the depts.

Comment: @AjitKumar Please select the answer if it works for you.